# AWS Amplify environment variable coming through as undefined when called

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-amplify, strapi

I'm launching my nextjs application through AWS Amplify and I have an environment variable that return undefined with called in my node application.

I defined the environment variable from the Amplify console shown here:

[Amplify Environment Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5aRoH.png)

The variable STRAPI is a 256 character string which according to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-amplify-branch-environmentvariable.html) I found should be ok.

Here is the code that uses the environment variables:

```
import qs from "qs";

/**
 * Get full Strapi URL from path
 * @param {string} path Path of the URL
 * @returns {string} Full Strapi URL
 */
export function getStrapiURL(path = "") {
  return `${
    process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL || "http://localhost:1337"
  }${path}`;
}

/**
 * Helper to make GET requests to Strapi API endpoints
 * @param {string} path Path of the API route
 * @param {Object} urlParamsObject URL params object, will be stringified
 * @param {Object} options Options passed to fetch
 * @returns Parsed API call response
 */
export async function fetchAPI(path, urlParamsObject = {}, options = {}) {
  // Merge default and user options
  const token = process.env.STRAPI;
  console.log("Token in process.env:");
  console.log(process.env.STRAPI);

  console.log("Token in token var:");
  console.log(token);
  const mergedOptions = {
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
    },
    ...options,
  };

  // Build request URL
  const queryString = qs.stringify(urlParamsObject);
  const requestUrl = `${getStrapiURL(
    `/api${path}${queryString ? `?${queryString}` : ""}`
  )}`;

  console.log("Request url:");
  console.log(requestUrl);

  // Trigger API call
  const response = await fetch(requestUrl, mergedOptions);

  // Handle response
  if (!response.ok) {
    console.error(response.statusText);
    throw new Error(`An error occurred please try again`);
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

*This code was lifted from another project credit to its original author*

NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL comes out fine it's just the STRAPI environment variable that comes out undefined.

*Side note: I'm fully aware you shouldn't log tokens and I 100% plan on regenerating the token once the issue is resolved.*

Here are the logs from CloudWatch and as you can see the NEXT_PUBLIC_STRAPI_API_URL comes out fine.

[cloudfront logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nF4k.png)

I'm not sure the issue here, but I've tried the following:

- Giving the STRAPI var a new value and it still came out as undefined after redeploying.
- I delete the env var and created a new one to see if there was some bug there and that did not resolve it after redeploying.
- I verified the setup is working locally on my machine.

Not sure what next steps to take here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is NextJS needed the environment variable to be prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_ to be exposed to the application. This was introduced in about NextJS 9. It's been awhile since I used NextJS.